# Is there a way to issue boilerplate debugger commands on the command line?

Tags: perl, debugging

I'd love to be able to do something like:

```
perl -d my-program.pl -c 'b postpone Foo::Bar::some_func'
```

i.e. specify as part of the invocation of `perl -d` a command that I would ordinarily enter at the debugger prompt, namely `b postpone Foo::Bar::some_func`.

Comment: Was gonna suggest `perl -pe'BEGIN { print "b postpone Foo::Bar::some_func\n" }' | perl -d my-program.pl`, but the debugger doesn't read from STDIN.

Comment: @ikegami drats, foiled!

Comment: From `man perldebug`, `@DB::typeahead` looks well-suited, but: "Note that @DB::typeahead is not a supported interface and is subject to change in future releases."

Answer (score 0):

From [`man perldebug`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldebug.html), you could use [source file](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldebug.html#source-file)

Put some common commands in a file and source that manually after starting the debugger.